# Authentication failed, even password is correct, using bcrypt hash method

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, bcrypt

I am having problem with **bcrypt** hash method and **mysql**. I'm using the `Bcrypt` class from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1338292).

I am creating login script and checking, if password is 
correct. I am comparing password from input and hashed 
password from DB.

```
$username= $_POST['username']; //username from input
$pass= $_POST['pass'];         //username from input

$query= mysql_query("SELECT pass FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    $row=  mysql_fetch_row($query);

$row[0];// hashed password, I echo $row[0] and it shows correct hashed password

$bcrypt = new Bcrypt(15);
$isGood = $bcrypt->verify($pass, $row[0]);

if ($isGood){
echo "Authentication succeeded";
          }
else { 
    echo"Authentication failed";
   }
```

Even $pass is correct, I always get 'Authentication failed'.
Any ideas, what can be wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what does `if($isGood)` check for???

Comment: [Bobby Tables' mother](http://xkcd.com/327/) would like to have a word with you

Comment: @soul It checks if the application is good. It fails at the moment.

Comment: Somehow I suppose `$bcrypt->hash` wasn't used to create the value stored in DB. Am I right? )

Comment: Of course you have Bcrypt class?

Comment: @soul
checking, if password from input and hashed password from DB equal.
in this example, I am using this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)
raina77ow, it is already added in registration script. or do you want to see code of it as well? :)

Comment: @ Damonsson, yes I do. honorable to mention, that $hash = $bcrypt->hash($pass) and $isGood = $bcrypt->verify($pass, $hash) is working fine. but if I get hased password from DB, verify function does not work :( I read many other questions with bcrypt issues, but can not find similar situation to mine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pass` column in your `users` table is not wide enough to store the complete hash; it should be at least 60 characters wide, i.e. `VARCHAR(60)`.

Btw, you should check out [PasswordLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-PasswordLib) as well, written and maintained by [ircmaxell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338665/ircmaxell), which also supports Bcrypt quite well.

Comment: yes, you are right. problem was with DB table, I found it before you answered. so now is ok. very stupid mistake :(

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$bcrypt = new Bcrypt(15);
$hash = $bcrypt->hash($pass);

echo $hash.' =? '.$row[0];
```

And look if it's equal

if yes, try something like this:

```
var_dump($hash);
var_dump($row[0]);
```

Must be equal

Comment: unfortunately, echo different hash's.. not equal.
let say, password is 'test', so hash will be equal every time, if pass is 'test'? I thinking, maybe it is something with salt..

Comment: `$row[0];// hashed password, I echo $row[0] and it shows correct hashed password` <- so, this is incorrect however?

Comment: problem was with DB table, should be `varchar(60)`. thank you for helping me :)